# Can't have a slug with the word `media` in it. Django

Tags: django, django-urls

### Setup

I have a very simple app where the main page display a list of items and if you click on an item you go the the item detail. Here is a part the model for such item:

```py
# projects/models.py

class Project(models.Model):
    ...
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from="website_title", always_update=True)
    ...
```

As you see the slug for the item is determined based on the name (it removes spaces, special characters, etc.)

Now, in my `urls.py` I have the following:

```py
# projects/urls.py 
urlpatterns = [
    path("", ProjectListView.as_view(), name="home"),
    path("<slug:slug>", ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name="project"),
]
```

### Problem

The problem is that if a project name contains the word media in it (in the beginning) then the resulting path will return an error. For example, if a project is called `MediaCMS` then the server will try the following url `https://builtwithdjango.com/mediacms`, but it will return an error (below).

[image]

The work around I found is to add underscore to the name of the project (i.e. `_MediaCMS`).

The issue is obviously due to some sort of mix and match between the project slug and the `MEDIA_URL`, which for me is the following:

```py
# builtwithdjango/settings.py
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")
```

### Note

Interestingly, this is not an issue, when on the local server. The following url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/mediacms`, works just fine.

Comment: Should you not be considering that having a url pattern without a prefix / suffix, and which can match any string without `/` in it is bad url design on your part? `project/<slug:slug>/` would honestly be a more descriptive and better urlpattern. Other than that you have likely configured NGINX incorrectly for the media files.

Comment: I did not worry about it, since I'm the only person who can add andremove project. So, there is no way of messing this up (no duplicated, or bad names). In return I get very nice and simplistic url.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out my NGINX config.